# GCP - Cloud endpoints service_name and configuration

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am studying Google Cloud Endpoints and I have some doubts about configuration.
I already work with appengine, but endpoints it is a little confuse for me.

I did this example:

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java

I did some changes for test other possibilities:

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <module>endpointsmodule</module>


    <basic-scaling>
        <max-instances>1</max-instances>
    </basic-scaling>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>

    <!-- [START env_variables] -->
    <env-variables>
        <env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME" value="${endpoints.service.prefix}.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com" />
        <env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION" value="1.0.0" />
    </env-variables>
    <!-- [END env_variables] -->
</appengine-web-app>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <!-- Wrap the backend with Endpoints Frameworks v2. -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.echo.Echo,com.example.echo.Echo2</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Route API method requests to the backend. -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/endpointsmodule/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Add a filter that fetches the service config from service management. -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Add a filter that performs Endpoints logging and monitoring. -->
    <!-- [START api_management] -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.api.control.extensions.appengine.GoogleAppEngineControlFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>endpoints.projectId</param-name>
            <param-value>${endpoints.project.id}</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>endpoints.serviceName</param-name>
            <param-value>${endpoints.service.prefix}.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>

    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- [END api_management] -->
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<endpoints.project.id>myprojectid</endpoints.project.id>
<endpoints.service.prefix>mymodule</endpoints.service.prefix>
```

**openapi.json**

```
{
 "swagger": "2.0",
 "info": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "title": "xxx"
 },
 "host": "myprojectid.appspot.com",
 "basePath": "/endpointsmodule",
 "schemes": [
  "https"
 ],
```

[image]

The doubts are:

Whats is the purpose of service_name? I did deploy of openapi.json and appengine module but in my Google Console still appear the name of my project in "service name".

this configuration: ENDPOINTS_CONFIG_ID, I can not see anywhere in my Google Console.

I would like that my endpoints receive requets in "enpoints-module"(appengine) that is appengine, not a default module.

All requests to endpoints happen through _ah/api ?

I am trying to do a request for this path:
https://myprojectid.appspot.com/endpointsmodule/echo/v1/echo

What is the correct value to ENDPOINTS_CONFIG_ID and ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION?

The exception when appengine starts:

```
repackaged.com.google.api.config.ServiceConfigException: Failed to fetch default config version for service 'myserviceprefix.endpoints.myprojectid.appspot.com'. No versions exist!
```

Answer (score 0):

The Endpoints service name is host field set in the OpenAPI specification. This has to match both the environment variable `ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME` and the `endpoints.serviceName` filter parameter.

Comment: Thanks @saiyr, I saw any examples like this:
echo-api.endpoints.[YOUR-PROJECT-ID].cloud.goog

What the service_name is that?
Do you know about ENDPOINTS_CONFIG_ID and ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION?